# Arch Linux fails to tty

Tags: arch-linux, liveusb

I'm trying to boot Arch Linux from a USB drive, but I cannot open pacman or whatever. I've downloaded the Arch Linux .ISO file and put it on a USB using Rufus, but it fails to load properly. I am still new to this Linux distro.

```
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/arch_201509
Error :'/dev/disk/by-label/arch_201509' device did not show up after 30 seconds...
Falling back to interactive prompt
You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when finished
sh: can't access tty ; job control turned off
```

Comment: You have lots of details but no clear question.

Comment: I try to boot archlinux from usb but cannot pacman or whatsoever... I've download archlinux .ISO and put it into usb by Rufus but it fail to load properly.I am still new to this Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is "Why doesn't the Arch Linux installation commence"? Then the likely answer is that the boot disk is labelled something other than "arch_201509". You can verify that by running `ls /dev/disk/by-label/arch_201509`. The solution is to change the disk label to the required one.